# Stress in the sentence "I'm proud of you, Hannah"

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, american-accent, word-stress

I know that we usually stress content words in a sentence and unstress function words as long as stress is not shifted for special emphasis.

In the sentence, "I'm proud of you, Hannah", I would probably stress the words "proud" and "Hannah" leaving the pronoun "you" unstressed. I think that stressing "you" doesn't make sense because I also provided the name of the person and clearly I don't make special emphasis. Am I right?

Comment: You are right.  Unless one were clearing up some miscommunication, where Hannah mistakenly believed that you were proud of Mary, in which case "you" would receive emphasis,  the sentence above would be spoken with the emphasis on *proud* and *Hannah*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It all depends on the context and exactly what you're trying to communicate:

> **I'm** proud of you, Hannah!

(others may be proud of you, but I want you to know that I am, too)

> I'm **proud** of you, Hannah!

(not disappointed in you, as you might be thinking)

> I'm proud of **you**, Hannah!

(others may have done well, but I want you to know particularly how I feel about you)